# Как тегу select задать класс в Django?

Tags: django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно добавить класс *'full-width'* к тегу *select*, который будет создаваться из класса *Question*

Файл **models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        ('russian', 'Русский'),
        ('english', 'English'),
    )

    language = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='russian')
```

файл **forms.py**

```
class UserQuestion(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('language',)
        labels = {
            'language': 'Выберите язык',
        }
        widgets = {
            'language': forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'full-width'})
            ),
        }
```

Хотел это сделать в forms.py, добавив атрибут, но там не получается.

Comment: Это нужно делать именно в forms, покажите, что, где и как у вас не получается

Comment: @andreymal в forms.py прописывал 
...
class Meta:
    model = Question
    widjets = {
        'language': CharField(attr={'class': 'full-width'})
    }
но в этом случае att подсвечивается как ошибка
Извиняюсь, не знаю, как здесь форматировать текст

Comment: Что значит "подсвечивается как ошибка"? Не пробовали игнориривать "подсвечивание" и запускать этот код? Документацию по CharField читали?

Comment: @andreymal, да, в документации находил, как стилизовать CharField: _'language': forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'full-width'}))_, запускал его (ничего не подсвечивалось), но показывается ошибка в браузере _'CharField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'_. Если убрать эту строку, то ошибка исчезает

Comment: Где именно показывалась-то? Я в своих проектах использовал именно такую строчку, и она отлично у меня работала. Покажите пример, в котором не работает

Comment: @andreymal, добавил информации в сам вопрос. Еще пробовал переопределить поле language (вне класса Meta), но поле отображается, как Input. Что-то мне подсказывает, что не туда пишу код.

Comment: Стоп-стоп, а зачем у вас CharField в виджетах? Просто `'language': forms.TextInput(...)` и всё вроде [согласно документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)

Comment: @andreymal, тогда это поле отображается просто как Input с текстом russian

Comment: А, забыл про select

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать последовать другой части документации и вместо всего этого написать `self.fields['language'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'full-width'})` в конструкторе `__init__` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, изменил на строку 'language': form.Select(...)  и заработало, как нужно. Добавьте это, как ответ - отмечу, как решенный вопрос

Comment: Хм, оно само подгрузило нужные choices? Отлично тогда

Comment: Может быть в новой версии так реализовали (пользуюсь 2.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Документация Django предлагает два способа изменения виджетов в ModelForm.

Первый — переопределить виджеты в словаре `widgets`. Туда надо пихать именно виджеты, а не field'ы:

```
class UserQuestion(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('language',)
        labels = {
            'language': 'Выберите язык',
        }
        widgets = {
            'language': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'full-width'}),
        }
```

Второй — не пихать свой виджет, а модифицировать стандартный в конструкторе (не забываем вызвать super):

```
class UserQuestion(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('language',)
        labels = {
            'language': 'Выберите язык',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['language'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'full-width'})
```